# Generate column names dynamically for a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

So, I am coverting a json into dataframe using and I'm successful in doing that. Below is my code:

```
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(json, c)))
colnames(df) <- gsub("X", "y",colnames(df))
```

So, it gives me column names like y1,y2,y3 etc. Is it possible if I could have these column names generated from 0 instead. So, the column names should be like y0,y1,y2 etc.

Comment: `names(df) <- paste0("y", 0:(ncol(df) - 1))`

Comment: look at `jsonlite` package and its `fromJSON` function to import Json to dataframe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the comments:

```
df <- data.frame(t(sapply(json,c))
colnames(df) <- paste0("y", 0:(ncol(df)-1))
```

Or if you want padded zeros

```
a <- seq(0,ncol(df)-1,1)
colnames(df) <- sprintf("y%02d",a)
```

Comment: Thanks for the catch, and the solution.  Put here for posterity and fake internet points.